# Bootstrap Navbar hamburger does not collapse when clicked

Tags: html, jquery, css, components, navbar

I am following a video course and did exactly as the instructor. His navbar hamburger collapses upon clicking but mine does not.
I've tried:
different browsers
rearranging the order and location of link and script tags for JQuery and bootstrap
looked through the bootstrap css file to see if there was a class attribute that was disabled

Could someone please help me out with why the hamburger button does not collapse?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Bootstrap Navbars</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#demo"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="demo">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- DEFAULT NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                >Dropdown <span class="caret"></span
              ></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                >Dropdown <span class="caret"></span
              ></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
      integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is about your libraries. Change them to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Bootstrap Navbars</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#demo"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Koffee</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="demo">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- DEFAULT NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                >Dropdown <span class="caret"></span
              ></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                >Dropdown <span class="caret"></span
              ></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Boostrap jQuery-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked Cagri, thank you so much. Can I ask why it was necessary to use older library versions?

Comment: It is not about older or newer version.  Version u used for jquery doesn't include code for open code. For example u can just change jquery with  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` and it will again work.

Comment: I didn't understand by what you meant when you said "doesn't include code for open code"
I googled "jquery open code" and wasn't sure on which topic to focus on
Can you direct me to an area I can research more to learn about this so it doesn't happen in future?

Comment: I mean some jquery versions doesnt match with boottsrap versions to use all bootsrap feaures. If u integrate wrong combination then some of bootsrap features will not work

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/ in bootsrap website u can find always combination which works correctly.

Comment: oh that makes sense, thank you for your teachings Çağrı, truly appreciated